# Subtracting ROW 2 FROM ROW 1

Tags: sql

How do I subtract rows from rows?  Basically, a group by rollup but with subtraction?

Dont know where to begin.  Basically, for every change at TABLE_NAME, subtract row 2 from row 1.

```
TABLE_NAME          REPORT_DATE COUNT_ROWS
dat_accounts        2019-10-08  10769524
dat_accounts        2019-10-06  10723077
dat_acct_events     2019-10-08  28196
dat_acct_events     2019-10-06  28179
dat_charges         2019-10-08  211955563
dat_charges         2019-10-06  211262985
dat_clinical        2019-10-08  10808351
dat_clinical        2019-10-06  10761904
dat_desk            2019-10-08  114
dat_desk            2019-10-06  114
dat_insurance       2019-10-08  10769524
dat_insurance       2019-10-06  10723077
dat_MRI             2019-10-08  11993228
dat_MRI             2019-10-06  11946781
dat_status_events   2019-10-08  178600
dat_status_events   2019-10-06  178600
dat_transactions    2019-10-08  70783124
dat_transactions    2019-10-06  70644574
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no row "1" or "2", unless a column contains those values.

Comment: Understood, I was just trying to use that convention in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given data where the REPORT_DATE for 1st row is always 2019-10-08 and 2nd row is always 2019-10-06 for the rows with the same TABLE_NAME

```
select t1.table_name, t1.count_rows - t2.count_rows
from T t1, T t2
where t1.table_name = t2.table_name
and t1.report_date = to_date('2019-10-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
and t2.report_date = to_date('2019-10-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If the REPORT_DATE can be any arbitrary date but the 1st row date is always greater than the 2nd row date:

```
select t1.table_name, t1.count_rows - t2.count_rows
from T t1, T t2
where t1.table_name = t2.table_name
and t1.report_date > t2.report_date;
```

Comment: Code 2 is more suitable.  Many thanks.  Can you explain how I would be able to keep the original tow rows too?

Comment: Never mid, I figured it out.  UNION ALL.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Provided rows are logically ordered by `REPORT_DATE`

```
   select * 
   from (
       select TABLE_NAME, REPORT_DATE
        , COUNT_ROWS - lead(COUNT_ROWS) over(partition by TABLE_NAME  order by REPORT_DATE) DELTA
       from mytable) t
   where DELTA is not null;
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but I do appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a diff between `row_2 - row_1`:

```
SELECT 
 o.TABLE_NAME
,o.REPORT_DATE
,o.COUNT_ROWS
,(SELECT i.COUNT_ROWS FROM TABLE_NAME i WHERE i.TABLE_NAME = o.TABLE_NAME AND i.REPORT_DATE < o.REPORT_DATE) as DIFF
FROM TABLE_NAME o
```

You can add a `GROUP BY` to show just the diff and table_name:

```
SELECT 
 o.TABLE_NAME
,(SELECT i.COUNT_ROWS FROM TABLE_NAME i WHERE i.TABLE_NAME = o.TABLE_NAME AND i.REPORT_DATE < o.REPORT_DATE) as DIFF
FROM TABLE_NAME o
GROUP BY o.TABLE_NAME
```

If SQL complains about the `GROUP BY` and columns not being included, you could insert to a temp_table and then query/ group by from that.

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but I do appreciate your effort.